# HTML5. I'm having trouble matching menu header to the ul background

Tags: css, html, html-lists

like i said in the title, I'm trying to match the menu header, which is a picture, on top of an ul that has a matching background picture with the menu header. No matter what i tried, there is still a gap between the header and the ul. Sorry if i sound confusing, here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0px 25px 45px;
background:url(ul.png) no-repeat 0 100%;
list-style-image:url(li.png);
}
table td { 
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top; 
}
ul li a:hover{
color: red;
padding-left: 10px;
}
img {
position: relative;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<table width="313" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="303" height="257"><img src="h3.png" width="224" height="35"  alt=""/><ul>
<li><a href="#">Future</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Health</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Life</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Money</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Phobias</a></li>
</ul></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, good luck! Oh, btw. any questions?

Comment: You most likely need to set `margin:0px; padding:0px` for your table elements, so that there isn't a gap.

Comment: @Charlie74 I tried what you suggested, but there is still a gap. Thanks though

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to merge the 2 images. Why not set an unique image to the table background ?

Comment: @vals ah, I have though of that and have already done it. However, the assignments specifically asked to do it this way. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all of those "gaps problems", think about including the reset.css stylesheet made by Eric A.

You can grab it here --> http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Include it before your `<style>` by writing :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="YOUR_PATH/css/reset.css" />
```